# How to create a column in PL/SQL that is a listagg of other column names that have null values for each row

Tags: plsql, ssms

Like the title says I am trying to create a column in PL/SQL that is a list aggregation of other column names that have null values for each respective column in each row without writing a case statement with dozens of when clause.

I am working with date/time data with lots of nulls and would like to create a column that shows all of the dates that are missing data for a report.

So if dates were missing from Column A ,B, and C for a specific row then the new columns' value for that row would be 'A,B,C'

How would I do this without writing case statements for each combination of columns that could be missing dates? I've started writing the case statements for each combo for now but don't want this to be my permanent solution.

I appreciate any insight.

Thanks!
Here is an example of my data:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | 2010-05-10 | 2011-01-05 |
| 2011-05-13 | NULL | NULL | 2010-11-10 | 2011-11-30 |
| 2009-07-21 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2011-02-02 |

I am trying to create column F.

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | 2010-05-10 | 2011-01-05 | A,B,C |
| 2011-05-13 | NULL | NULL | 2010-11-10 | 2011-11-30 | B,C |
| 2009-07-21 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2011-02-02 | B,C,D |

Comment: I'm new to the website and having a difficult time getting it to format correctly bear with me. I am just looking to add the column to my query.

Comment: run this https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ and edit the question to show proper tabular data with column names, etc. nobody can read what you have put just in the comment sections.  show what SQL you have attempted.

Comment: there is no easy way to do that without explicitly referencing the column names.